# Get the original class from Objects inside a List

Tags: java

As an exercise i have to write a very simple software for a swimming pool.

The parent class is **User**.

**Adult** and **Child** are two classes that extend User.

**DisabledChild** and **DisabledAdult** extend User and implement an interface **Disabled** with a single extra-method that just prints "i'm disabled!"

In main i create different objects of these classes depending on their age parameter and a 'disabled' boolean, then i put them into a list, like this:

```
public void insertData()
{
   int age;
   Adult a = null;
   DisabledAdult da = null;
   Scanner scanIn = new Scanner(System.in);
   List l = new ArrayList();

  do {

   System.out.println("Insert user name, type 'quit' to exit");
   name = scanIn.next();

   System.out.println("Insert age");
   age = scanIn.nextInt();

        if (age > 16) {
            System.out.println("Is the adult disabled? ( y/n)");
            String disabled = scanIn.next();
            if("y".equals(disabled))
            {
               da = new DisabledAdult();
               l.add(da); // l is a list!
            } else
            {
               a = new Adult();
               l.add(a);
            }
        }

        else{
           // similar as above, but for children.
        }

    } while (!"quit".equals(name));

    scanIn.close();
```

Here comes the problem: when i put stuff inside my list they become Objects, and i can't go back to their original class even with .getClass().getName(). So i can't use their specific methods, like the one implemented from Disabled interface.

I'm forced to cast Obj into an User (because everyone in the swimming pool is an user), like this:

```
        for (Object obj : l) {
              User u = (User) obj;
    }
```

**But i can't use the extra-methods of DisabledAdult or DisabledChild because they are defined in the interface Disabled, not User!**

If i do

```
obj.getClass().getName();
```

I can see their original class, but I can only access Object methods.

I think i could do something like:

```
if (obj instanceof Adult){
    Adult a = (Adult) obj;
}
if (obj instanceof Child){
    Child c = (Child) obj;
}
...
```

But it looks horrible because i should check this for every kind of user, if they are disabled or not, etc.

What can i do?

Thank you.

Comment: @Andreas You don't have to assume that everyone can change languages early. Some people have to use Java, especially those in AP Computer Science.

Comment: This is OO done terribly wrong, not a case against OO.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede See my comment on your answer.

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi Twelve years ago would you have said the same thing about learning pointer arithmetic in C? Why are we teaching our kids last decade's tech. Sure the kid needs to complete this work in Java, but I encourage him to seek a language where this sort of everyday logic is elegant.

Answer (score 3):

Use [generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) for your list. Since all of the objects in `l` are `User`s, you should specify that as the type parameter.

Instead of:

```
List l = new ArrayList();
```

Use:

```
List<User> l = new ArrayList<User>();
// or List<User> l = new ArrayList<>(); if you are on Java 7 or higher.
```

This way, you don't need to cast back into `User`s as you get them from your list.

Additionally, to check for disabled users, you can do this:

```
if(user instanceof Disabled) {
    Disabled disabledUser = (Disabled) user;
    //do disabled-specific stuff here on disabledUser, which is the same as user
}
```

This will allow you to do disabled-specific stuff to the disabled users.

Answer (score 2):

You should declare your list like this, using [generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/):

```
 List<User> l = new ArrayList<>();
```

If you then need to use the methods of the `Disabled` interface, you will have to check the type and cast.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should be using generics, i.e., a `List<User>` instead of just a `List`.  If this is for a class and you're being taught to do it the long-obsolete way, find a better teacher.

Second, differentiating disabled and non-disabled users in the manner you describe is outrageously bad OO modeling.  Normally, a `User` being disabled would simply be a property, and `User` would have methods like `setDisabled()` and `isDiabled()`.  If the point of the exercise is to learn about inheritance, you might instead have a method like `describeSelf()` which in `User` prints "I'm not disabled" and which is overridden in `DisabledUser` to print something else.  You could then call this method on instances of both types without testing the actual class and performing a cast.

I sincerely hope this exercise is designed to teach you what not to do.

Comment: It's a tradeoff. Sometimes you may want to implement certain methods only relevant to certain types of objects, and changing them to properties means that you'll have to implement them in all objects and change them to runtime checks from compile-time.

Comment: In such cases, you should almost always be handling instances of those subclasses *as* instances of those subclasses.  Outside of `equals(...)` methods, legitimate reasons to test the actual type of an object are extremely rare.